# Why is manna not a part of the celebration of Sukkot?

Tags: sukkot, mon-manna

Manna was an important feature of the daily lives of the Jews in the 40 years in the midbar.  Why is this daily miracle not even mentioned during the celebration of Sukkos?

Comment: This is a miracle which is related to every day -- as such, some people say Parshat Hamon every day and don't wait until Sukkot.

Comment: Why should it be tied to Sukkos specifically? Also, why specifically the Manna? The well of Miriam was just as important.

Comment: @DonielF Link to Succos is logical because Succos is about living in the wilderness for 40 years.  I agree with you about the well of Miriam.

Comment: @YehudaW Sukkos is specifically about the Clouds of Glory, or the literal huts. Not about living in general. Anyway, you should include that in the OP.